# Horizontal NSCollectionView in vertical NSTableView does not select until collection view is clicked

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview, nscollectionview

I have a weird question regarding NSCollectionView. Basically, I have a collection view that scrolls horizontally in a vertically scrolling table view. I have implemented the data source and delegate of the collection view within my `NSTableCellView` subclass. The data source works just fine and the collection view is able to load some images.

Here comes the problem. I want the collection view to be selectable. I have implemented this delegate method into my table cell view subclass:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, didSelectItemsAt indexPaths: Set<IndexPath>) {
    // Do things here
}
```

This method works, but with a caveat. It only gets called when I click on an empty space in the collection view first and then selecting a cell. If I only click on a cell, it will not get called, which is quite bizarre to me. Any idea on how to fix this?

I designed the table cell view in the storyboard, the collection view has it's `Selectable` and `Allow Empty Selection` checked in the storyboard. `Allow Multiple Selection` is not checked because I don't want multiple selection, but I tried having it on and it doesn't change anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclass `NSTableView`. In your subclass, override `validateProposedFirstResponder(_:for:)` to return true for your collection view and its subviews (or maybe just return true always).

Comment: Yes. I just override the method to always return true since I have a table view that does not allow selection. Being finding this for a while Thanks!